# How to sanitalize string with nested html tags but keep <em> tag?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub, html-sanitizing

I am trying to sanitalize Solr search results, cause it has html tags inside:

`ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize( result_string )`

It is easy to sanitalize not highlighted string like: `I know <ul><li>ruby</li> <li>rails</li></ul>`.

But when results is highlighted I have additional important tags inside - `<em>` and `</em>`:

`I <em>know</em> <<em>ul</em>><<em>li</em>><em>ruby</em></<em>li</em>> <<em>li</em>><em>rails</em></<em>li</em>></<em>ul</em>>`.

So, when I sanitalize string with nested html and highlighting tags, I get string with peaces of htmls tags. And it is bad :)

How can I sanitalize highlighted string with `<em>` tags inside to get correct result (string with `<em>` tags only)?

I found the way, but it's slow and not pretty:

```
string = 'I <em>know</em> <<em>ul</em>><<em>li</em>><em>ruby</em></<em>li</em>> <<em>li</em>><em>rails</em></<em>li</em>></<em>ul</em>>'

['p', 'ul', 'li', 'ol', 'span', 'b', 'br'].each do |tag| 
  string.gsub!( "<<em>#{tag}</em>>",  '' )
  string.gsub!( "</<em>#{tag}</em>>", '' )
end

string = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize string, tags: %w(em)
```

How can I optimize it or do it using some better solution?
to write some regex and remove html_tags, but keep `<em>` and `</em>` e.g.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I may have not understood well your question, but I think you should specify what to sanitize and what what to sanitize not through an option value:

ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize( result_string, tags: %w(em) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call gsub! to discard all tags but keep only   tags that are independent, or that are not included in html tag.

```
result_string.gsub!(/(<\/?[^e][^m]>)|(<<em>\w*<\/em>>)|(<\/<em>\w*<\/em>>)/, '')
```

would do the trick

To explain:

```
# first group (<\/?[^e][^m]>) 
# find all html tags that are not <em> or </em>

# second group (<<em>\w*<\/em>>)
# find all opening tags that have <em> </em> inside of them like:
# <<em>li</em>>   or <<em>ul</em>>

# third group (<\/<em>\w*<\/em>>)
# find all closing tags that have <em> </em> inside of them:
# </<em>li</em>>   or  </<em>ul</em>>

# and gsub replaces all of this with empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [sinitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize):

```
Custom Use (only the mentioned tags and attributes are allowed, nothing else)
<%= sanitize @article.body, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style) %>
```

So, something like that should work:

```
sanitize result_string, tags: %w(em)
```

Comment: If I sanitalize string `I <em>know</em> <<em>b</em>><em>ruby</em></<em>b</em>>`,        I will get in result `I know <b>ruby</b>`.   But I need to get `I <em>know</em> <em>ruby</em>` in result...

Comment: So, I need at first - delete <em> tags inside html tags. And than delete html tags, but keep <em> which was remained...

Answer (score 0):

With an additional parameter to [sanitize](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize), you can specify which tags are allowed.

In your example, try:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize( result_string, tags: %w(em) )
```

It should do the trick

Comment: it does not help, cause when I have <em> inside of some html tag, sanitalize does not work good ( '<<em>p</em>>' e.g. )